# 2009 Chevy Malibu turn signal problems

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, turn-signal

I have a 2009 Chevy Malibu LT. I had a check engine light come on last week. I went to a parts store and the guy working there plugged a small, hand held computer into my car under the steering column. He found out I needed a new MAF sensor. I bought one, installed it and that problem was fixed.

The problem I'm having now is that ever since he plugged in his computer under my steering column, my blinkers don't work right. When I put the left blinker on, I have to hold it down or it won't stay on. When I put the right blinker on, I have to turn it off by hand or it won't go off. Is it possible that he bumped something under there and I need to have something readjusted so my blinkers will work right again?

Comment: What he put under your dash is called a Code Reader, which is a tool to read the engine codes, which the car automatically records to help diagnostics.  It is unlikely (as is near impossible, I think, unless I'm missing something) that that procedure could mess up the blinker signal.  How long have you been having this problem?

Comment: @cullub maybe the guy hit the switch with his head or something...

Answer (score -1):

There is a little plastic piece inside your blinker lever that breakers off.  Usually only one side won’t work correctly (example won’t stay on, have to hold it down to blink or won’t self cancel).  You can buy the whole lever for few dollars. Real easy fix. I changed this on my 2009 Malibu LTZ.  YouTube this if you already haven’t.  There are some really good videos changing this.